# Join two slices and go through them with a sliding window using iterators on Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

How to join two slices and move through them with a sliding window using Rust iterators?
At the same time, I know the size of the first slice. Example of expected code, but it doesn't work:

```
fn sl_win<'a, const N: usize>(y0: &'a [f64; N], y: &'a [f64]) -> impl Iterator<Item = f64> + 'a {
y0.iter()
    .chain(y.iter())
    .windows(N) // no method named `windows` found for struct `std::iter::Chain`
    .map(|w| w.iter().sum::<f64>())
```

Comment: Probably easiest to write your own iterator that just yields pairs of slices that, if concatenated, would form the correct window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tuple_window` from itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows).

This can't be supported in std because `windows` is an iterator of slices and slices have to be contiguous. The `chain` means a discontinuity. `tuple_windows` will copy every item into a tuple and yield that, so it doesn't have that issue.

If that's not suitable, then you can use something like a `VecDeque`, shifting items in and out and summing as needed. `Iterator::scan` could be a good idea for convenience to compose that.

Or copy both slices into a vector, and `windows` over it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve this:

```rust
struct TwoSlices<'a, const N: usize, T> {
    first: &'a [T; N],
    second: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, const N: usize, T> IntoIterator for TwoSlices<'a, N, T> {
    type Item = (&'a [T], &'a [T]);
    type IntoIter = TwoSlicesIter<'a, N, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        TwoSlicesIter {
            slices: self,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

struct TwoSlicesIter<'a, const N: usize, T> {
    slices: TwoSlices<'a, N, T>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, const N: usize, T> Iterator for TwoSlicesIter<'a, N, T> {
    type Item = (&'a [T], &'a [T]);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let Self {
            slices: TwoSlices { first, second },
            index,
        } = self;

        let l = *index;
        let r = (l + N) % (2 * N);

        *index += 1;

        if let Some(s1) = first.get(l..r) {
            Some((s1, [].as_slice()))
        } else if let Some(s1) = first.get(l..) {
            second.get(..l).map(|s2| (s1, s2))
        } else {
            second.get(r..l).map(|s2| ([].as_slice(), s2))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let v2 = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
    let slices = TwoSlices {
        first: &v1,
        second: &v2,
    };
    for window in slices {
        println!("{:?}", window);
    }
}
```

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], [])
([2, 3, 4], [15])
([3, 4], [15, 16])
([4], [15, 16, 17])
([], [15, 16, 17, 18])
([], [16, 17, 18, 19])
```

Now your rolling sum can be implemented as:

```rust
println!(
    "{:?}",
    slices
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(s1, s2)| s1.iter().chain(s2).sum::<i32>())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
);
```

```
[10, 24, 38, 52, 66, 70]
```

Comment: `TwoSlices` is a misnomer because it does not in fact hold to slices (`&[T; N]` isn't a slice).